# How to read multiple lines of input from user using fgets and write it into a file using fputs in C?

Tags: c, file, fgets, fputs

I wanted to read input from user (multiple lines) and write it into a file using fputs().

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 FILE *fp;
 char s[25];
 fp=fopen("myname","w");
 if(fp==NULL)
 {
  perror("Error opening file\n");
  exit(1);
 }

 while(fgets(s,25,stdin)!=NULL)
  fputs(s,fp);
 fclose(fp);
 return 0;
}
```

After getting input from user, i am using Ctrl+C to close the input prompt of the program (I'm using linux). Then if i open the file, it contains nothing. How could I resolve this?

Is there anything wrong with the usage of fputs() & fgets()?

Comment: Your code will break for lines of 25 bytes. You could use `fgets(s, sizeof(s)-1, stdin)` and you'll better `memeset(s, 0, sizeof(s));` before. And `getline` is a better function for this (because it allocates the line dynamically).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, the man page for `fgets` says `fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream  and stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by s..... A '\0' is stored after the last character in the buffer`. So, it is safe to have 25 in `fgets()` call. I tested this code with lines longer than 25 chars. The reason for not working is buffering. Adding `fflush(fp)` solved it. 

Sorry for the late comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`C-C`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C) likely kills the process, because of buffering, the lines won't get to the file (unless there's a lot of them and they fill the buffer).

You should end the output with `C-D` (Unix) or `C-Z` (Dos), not `C-C`.

As a side note: `fgets` doesn't strip the newline and `fputs` adds its own. But I guess you were going to notice that :-)

Comment: Thanks buddy, You are right. Now I', getting proper output :)